# Regex to check if string only contain digits and is 11 characters/digits long?

Tags: c#, regex

currently I am using:

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(searchValue, @"^\d{11}.*") && searchValue.Length == 11)
   {
     // Do something
   }
```

How can I alter the regex to also check the length and not to use the && operator?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's wrong with the `&&` operator?

Comment: @Danny - nothing in itself.  It's just redundant if the regex covers a test for the same condition.

Comment: You shouldn't use the \d unless you know what you are doing. Use [0-9]. \d will catch non-european digits. new Regex(@"\d").IsMatch("" + (char)0x660) == true! (0x660 is Arabic-Indic Digit Zero, ٠)

Comment: @xanatos - interesting.  Thanks - never knew that!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Changing the pattern to

```
@"^\d{11}$"
```

Should do it

Comment: @BoltClock - yes, but that is implicit in the question (it is the *purpose* of the question)

Answer (score 2):

Use the following expression:

`^\d{11}$`

Answer (score 1):

I tend to use the [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm) tool for designing regex patterns, especially as they get complex.  It shows a breakdown that clearly tells you what each bit of the regex is doing.  Agree with other posters (Marc/Logicnp) for the answer to the OP's problem.